# processing a very noisy signal

Tags: signal-analysis, noise, ecg

I work on an ECG signal that I collect from a sensor, and it is very noisy. Having researched it above I read that FFT or so Nyquist-Shawon's casting theories were advised, being novice in the field thanks for advising me some methods would be best.

[image]

Comment: Is *"...Nyquist-Shawon's casting..."* supposed to be ["Nyquist-Shannon sampling"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nyquist%E2%80%93Shannon_sampling_theorem)? (Also, there does not appear to be any electrocardiogram signal in this trace. It is all noise. How was it acquired?)

Comment: from a sensor named Bitalino that contains 3 electrodes (Positive, Negative and Neutral) that I connect to specific body parts.
I collect the data and visualize the signal via a Bluetooth that restrained the resulatta on the sensor interface named OpenSignals

Comment: that's exactly it, The sensor does not return at all the ECG signal that it is supposed to send back

Comment: Before you get to processing the signal to try and see if you can reduce the noise via a computational technique (e.g. filtering), you need to make sure that the analog part is working correctly. In this case it does not. You need to make sure that all three electrodes are making good contact with the skin and ensure that you don't have any problems in any other contact point on the signal path.

Comment: Yes, but what is the best way to process a signal?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: I try to correct the signal noises in order to have a correct ECG signal

What do you think is the most effective way to correct noise in a siganl?

Thank you